# Pimcore database imported but no Data Objects available

Tags: database, pimcore, data-objects

I recently installed a copy of an existing Pimcore-environment on my local machine with XAMPP.
I am able to log into the admin interface. The database and all class-definitions are imported.

The Data Objects panel is still empty.
What am I missing so that I have them available here as well?

Kind regards
Philipp

Comment: Did you rebuild the classes? If yes try to resave the object_ views in the database.

Answer (score 2):

To copy from an environment to another you need the database dump as well as the content inside the `var/` directory.

In your case you need to copy `var/classes/` folder to your local machine and run `bin/console pimcore:deployment:classes-rebuild -c`